# Brute force attack AES 192b

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

I have a task where I have to brute force a .enc file encrypted with AES-192  in CBC mode.

So the first thing I've done is trying an offline dictionary attack using Java and the Crypto library, the problem is that an average word in the dictionary is 8 bit long so the password must have been salted in some way.
The problem is that the program that I wrote keep outputting different password at every execution and the output is just unreadable text.

here is the main:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bruteForceFile();
    }   

    /*
     * Tries to brute force the file reading all the possible keys from a dictionary
     * */
    private static void bruteForceFile() {

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Starting brute force/dictionary attack:");
        try {
            byte[] file = cipherText.cipherText.getInstance().getFileArray();
            bruteForceWrapper enc = new AES(OperatingMode.CBC).bruteForceFile(file);
            System.out.println("decription succeded, key : " + enc.key + " elapsed time: " + enc.elapsedSeconds +"s");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Decripted message:\n");
            System.out.println(new String(enc.data));


        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the AES class:

```
/**
 *Advanced Encryption Standard as specified by NIST in FIPS 197. Also known as the Rijndael 
 *algorithm by Joan Daemen and Vincent Rijmen, 
 *AES is a 128-bit block cipher supporting keys of 128, 192, and 256 bits.
 */
public class AES extends cipher.AbstractCipher {


    public AES(OperatingMode opm) {
        super(opm);
        super.enablePadding();
    }


    @Override
    protected String getMode() {
        if(opm == OperatingMode.CBC) {
            if(padding) 
                return "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

            return "AES/CBC/NoPadding";
        }

        else {
            if(padding) 
                return "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";

            return "AES/ECB/NoPadding";
        }
    }



    @Override
    public encriptionWrapper encript(byte[] plainText,AbstractCipherKey key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public encriptionWrapper decript(byte[]cipherText,AbstractCipherKey key) {

        StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();

        if(super.print) {
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Starting " + this.toString() + " decryption" + " in " 
                    + opm.toString() + " mode."+ " (" + this.getMode() + ")");

        }
        try {


            Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            AESCipherKey aes_key = (AESCipherKey)key;
            byte[] b_key = aes_key.getPassword().getBytes("UTF-8");

            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            b_key = sha.digest(b_key);
            b_key = Arrays.copyOf(b_key, 16); 

            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(b_key, "AES");

            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);// decode with base64 to get bytes


            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(cipherText);
            // create new string based on the specified charset

            if(super.print) {

                System.out.println("Encryption ended. Elapsed Time: " + timer.getSeconds() + "s");
                System.out.println("encrypted message length: " + utf8.length);
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");

            }

            return new encriptionWrapper(utf8,timer.getSeconds());


        } catch (Exception e) {

            /*if(e.getClass() == BadPaddingException.class) {
                System.out.println("attempt failed....");
            }*/

            if(super.print) {
                System.out.println(this.toString() + " decryption failed. \n");
                System.out.println("decryption ended. Elapsed Time: " + timer.getSeconds() + "s");
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Try to brute force an encrypted file with AES
     */
    public bruteForceWrapper bruteForceFile(byte[] encrypted) {

        StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
        Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();
        bruteForceWrapper wrapper;
        super.print = false;

        System.out.print("Decrypting...");
        while(1 == 1) {
            if(dic.getProvidedWords().size()%10 == 0) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            encriptionWrapper enc = decript(encrypted,new AESCipherKey(dic.getWord()));
            if(enc != null) {
                wrapper = new bruteForceWrapper(enc.data, watch.getSeconds());
                break;
            }

        }
        super.print = true;
        wrapper.tried_keys = dic.getProvidedWords();

        wrapper.key = dic.getProvidedWords().get(dic.getProvidedWords().size() - 1);
        return wrapper;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AES";
    }

}
```

Finally here is the AESCipherKey class:

```
public class AESCipherKey extends AbstractCipherKey{


    private String SHA_TEC = "SHA-1";


    public AESCipherKey(String key) {
        super(key);
    }

    /**
     *Return the desription of the safeness of the key(unsafe is user generated)
     */
    @Override
    public String getKeySafenessDescription() {
        if(isKeySafe) {
            return "(safe key)";
        }else
            return "(unsafe key)";
    }



    @Override
    public boolean validate() {

        if(super.isKeySafe)
            return true;

        if(super.getByteArray().length != 16) {
            System.out.println("Invalid AES key: " + super.key);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void generateSecureKey() {
        KeyGenerator keyGen;
        try {
            keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keyGen.init(256);
            super.safeKey = keyGen.generateKey();
            super.isKeySafe = true;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("Error generating AES safe key");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return super.key;
    }

}
```

So I think that the problem is around here:

```
 byte[] b_key = aes_key.getPassword().getBytes("UTF-8");

                MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                b_key = sha.digest(b_key);
                b_key = Arrays.copyOf(b_key, 16); 

                SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(b_key, "AES");
```

but I'm not able to find the error, here some output of the decryption:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Starting brute force/dictionary attack:
Decrypting................decription succeded, key : enantiopathia elapsed time: 12.995s
--------------------------------------------------------
Decripted message:

"��t����O����m�V��}s1��i#a7� B<2�B֯�R�E�\!��v���k��WK�m��'hՒ���g�y�$�s�ug���
X��l=qYX�����F%�y)���>��r܅͞��i��L'FG��c6-�}���-�|�L�#�n���Ӧ���)�\�o�2|?7/ə���Lc�����-
�/���*���"sK���*[U�ɮ�����s��ec�P��z�6v�����Ov��1e����w�5����t�{s�%���|��W���'�3�^�H�Td��k1���S���l�8��Žѕ���XZ�X�Eiq��K���|�'�Wi��
E2-�k�Zm��
�͞�+tj��p�o\m���jc\���ؠ_v�F�k;���$\O��JW!�zD3cZ�@���N�T�J!^c��<��+���)[sK�=�Sf���Tm���J>�i�tc���1��`ɱs
,,uO��zt� �Ү>j�6��xe�,�z��l�$jW�����n��g��~M��^�s-����}kDr���`ݶ��4��?��hT�G�߿E�Z�w����&��'��фAz��}�-��r�W�2=����ƛ�i�!��Ⱥu�J�8_d��z���9h�]��yi�A�6D�0H�R����g#��������>rS1�e�供�F����H�E[m�����Syc��糠�)��"��b�޻�0%�¤����
o70T&&�T�06�q�F��X`�V��u{1`&Xkx ��7�����|�v
2_�y��VL6z�xu��95�r�H'g�E�J�(\WY�T������T���kXM�bG�^kppڀ@�h�1�9�[���Ǽ�T<�/Oo�B =�iw����Ef��G�S�c<����������W�
�<�H�N����$�m�-=�;�*��].��v��n���&�V��D����_�{9��+��:����̶F0��|�1�9��p�9�*  �Rs�Ͱ�Ckl5ͫ�jGB��!��m�h
/��*г-�z�H�w�)Q����p��!� B�p�H֌˦eOŹ��������< ��Ǹ��[����uP��q�n�T���ǈ����yrЙ-$�i��X����T~�R��4�xό~]��G��e�dÖnI��&b{�=�&��Bi�y���%|���E���H�=�k�~į_�6PӬ׫��D|~
M ;��BK�'�p����o:8��0]������ً   �&�k9��2�0�̟WtFy���t�>?GS��� W.����tG�R��$\V�'�����'�&��a����#�b�9�בȨ�yl�+J�M���rƠ�D�0H��B�w;��8\�!���.%��yc��~�9�X ;hq�)�&E�
�W��?�D�-:��,t�f柟.�-P�f�\˲�=S.�&
���X޳]�����Z��׸���������j�A(�]�����m�*U'"6��g��jw��
```

Comment: Decrypting  AES-CBC encrypted data *with the wrong key* will result in a seemingly random sequence of bytes. Trying to print those bytes out as a character string is not very useful, as you have demonstrated. What sort of output were you expecting?

Comment: When the key is wrong the library just throw a BadPaddingException: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/BadPaddingException.html) so it will return a null wrapper and continue with the loop, anyway it suppose to be a poem(so text).

Comment: You might only get that exception if you are using a supported padding method different from `NOPADDING`. It's hard to tell from your code. Also: you are **not guaranteed** to get that exception for a wrong key even when using PKCS5/7 padding. The probability of **not** getting that exception when decrypting with a wrong key is a little greater than 1/256.

Comment: So you suggest to try NOPADDING and see?

Comment: I would need more information about what the plaintext is and how the plaintext was *encrypted* to understand to answer that question.

Comment: Unfortunately all I know is that the plain text is supposed to be a text file (a poem) and it was encrypted using OpenSSL 1.1 with AES using a 192b key in CBC mode, I don't know much more. The task is about trying to simulate a brute force attack because the key is suppose to be vulnerable to offline Dictionary attack.

Comment: Well, that information actually helps. One way to proceed is to attempt decrypt using `NOPADDING`, then count the number of spaces used to separate words and count how many words are in a dictionary for the language of the poem. More advanced techniques are possible as well. If the counts are high enough (i.e. it "looks" like it could be valid plaintext) then save off that key for later retesting. However, if padding is used then checking for proper padding is a very efficient first test that can be used to your advantage. That's why it helps greatly to know exactly how it was encrypted.

Comment: No, OpenSSL defaults to PKCS#7 padding, so using `PKCS5Padding` is fine as test (although using `NoPadding` and checking the resulting padding yourself would allow you to skip the inefficient exception handling). Then indeed you need to check if the resulting plaintext is what you expect it to be (e.g. printable ASCII, for starters). Of course, I hope your key derivation mechanism matches the one used for the ciphertext, or you're not going to find anything squared.